# Generar oauth code en docusing con python

Tags: python, fastapi

Hola compañeros estoy utilizando las apis de docusing para un proyecto, es la primera vez que las utilizo y bueno mi problema es el siguiente: al querer consumir las apis me pide dos tokens el jwt y el code de oauth, el problema lo tengo al generar el code de oauth, según veo en la pagina de docusing, se genera al ingresar al siguiente link.

**[https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7BiKey%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bcallback%7D)**

Saben si se puede de alguna forma automatizar este proceso, ya intente consumir de varias formas esta url con python y no lo he conseguido, la redirección al callback es obligatoria para generar el code.

**endpoint para guardar el code**

```
@login.get('/token/oauth')   
async def token_oauth(code):
    check_oauth = Oauth_docusing.select().first()
    
    if check_oauth:
        qry=Oauth_docusing.update({Oauth_docusing.code_grant : code
                        }).where(Oauth_docusing.id == check_oauth.id)
        qry.execute()
    else:
        oauth = Oauth_docusing.create(
            code_grant = code  
        )

    return code
```

**Como estoy intentando consumir la url**

```
async def obtener_code_grant():  
  url = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}'
  
  response = requests.get(url)
  print(response.content)
  return response.content
```

Saben como automatizar la generación de este code, o alguna alternativa de acceso a las apis?